# Descargar un archivo desde Sql con el mismo nombre con el que fue subido

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC y ocupo descargar el archivo desde sql y que se descargue con el mismo nombre en que anteriormente fue subido a la base de datos

De momento tengo este codigo para la desacarga

```
    public ActionResult VerDocumento(string pIdDocumento)
    {
        byte[] pdf = db.ExDocumentos.Where(r => r.IdDocumento == pIdDocumento).Single().Datos;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "nombre.pdf");

    }
```

Lo que dice ExDocumentos es el nombre de la tabla de la base de datos en sql

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica el nombre de la clase `ExDocumentos`. Indica también el código de la Acción donde subes el documento a la Base de Datos.